Fast Fourier transformation in a lattice $H_{\vec{R}}(m,n,l)$ to $H_{\vec{k}}(a,b,c)$
I have a Hamiltonian defined on a lattice grid $H_{\vec{R}}(m,n,l)$ with $m,n,l \in \mathbb{N}$ and ranging in [-M,M], [-N,N], [-L,L]. Based on the $H_{\vec{R}}(a,b,c)$, a discrete Fourier transformation from real space $H_{\vec{R}}(m,n,l)$ to momenta space $H_{\vec{k}}(m,n,l)$ reads
$$H_{\vec{k}}(a,b,c)=\sum_{-M}^{M} \sum_{-N}^{N} \sum_{-L}^{L} H_{\vec{R}}(m,n,l)e^{2 \pi i (\frac{am}{A} +\frac{bn}{B} +\frac{cl}{C} ) }$$
with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ and ranging in [0,A], [0,B], [0,C].
I tried to achieve this in python package like numpy, scipy via FFT to accelerating my calculation, however, I have encountered a problems while the fft.fftn or fft.ifftn in numpy could only perform calculations with m,n,l ranging in the positive zone [0,M], [0,N], [0,L], are there any advises or solutions to fix this problem?

Stackoverflow may be more appropriate, but in general you can use fft.fftfreq and fft.fftshift
